How do I annotate a molecule on Chemfig?
I want to annotate a molecule like the image below 
I have the following code for the molecule
    \schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig[double bond sep = 4pt]{*5(((-[::180]*6(-=-=-=))(-[::-90]*6(-=-=-=)))-\chembelow{N}{{H}}-(=O)-\chemabove{N}{H}-(=O)-)}}{Phenytoin}
\schemestop

I'm stuck because I'm looking through the Chemfig manual (https://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) but I can't find an instance of it using an arrow from an arbitrary point to a molecule, it has to be over a molecule or reaction arrow, which is not what I'm aiming for here. I also tried to name the hydrogen as H1 with @{H1} to start off but in the \chemabove environment it just adds another H1 instead of labelling that H an H1. Can anyone help :)

You need to place a position marker (@{a1}) at H, but in the "chemabove" and "charge" commands the markers do not work.
I placed an "invisible link" to position the marker
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig[double bond sep = 4pt]{*5(((-[::180]*6(-=-=-=))(-[::-90]*6(-=-=-=)))-\chembelow{N}{{H}}-(=O)-\chemabove{N}{H}(-[2,.3,,,,draw=none]@{a1})-(=O)-)}}{Phenytoin}
\arrow(@{a1}--){<-}[30,1]$pK_a=8.3$
\schemestop
\end{document}


Another way to place a marker on the H is to place the H above the N using a short, invisible bond, N(-[2,.3,,,,draw =none]@{a1}H without using \chemabove or \charge

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemname{\chemfig[double bond sep=4pt]{
    *5(((-[::180]*6(-=-=-=))(-[::-90]*6(-=-=-=)))
    -\chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)-@{pka}\chemabove{N}{H}-(=O)-)
}}{Phenytoin}
\chemmove{\draw[stealth-, shorten <=2pt] (pka.east) ++(0,2ex) -- ++(5:1) node[anchor=west, font=\footnotesize] {$\mathrm{p}K_{\mathrm{a}} = 8.3$};}
\end{document}


